# java web application and their servers hosting

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, servlets, web-hosting

I have developed a java web application using JSF 2.0(Facelets) on GlassFish 3.1.1 with a MySql 5 DB,
its more of a company website offering their services online.

I tried to go for the Bulidng my own server hosting, but the company refused and preferred to go for online hosting.

So now am going for online hosting and my questions is this:-

Does JSF (or any other java EE framework) need their own type of servers, or if a server can host jsp/servlets is capable of hosting JSF apps ?

and does applications developed using Glassfish work on TomCat servers or JBOSS or any other?

Comment: A classic answer - it depends! Your question is too broad, I'd like to ask why you developed a corporate application without even knowing on which platform to host it?

Comment: Not sure of the answers to your questions, but the company that hosts my Java enabled sites has always been very good at answering inquiries.  You can get in contact with them through their [homepage](http://www.cheap-jsp-hosting.com/).

Comment: @home because I told them in the beginning that we're gonna make the servers, but u know how requirments change with companies, an thats when they told me that they wanted to go online.

Comment: and my question is simple, does apps built on glassfish can run on any other servers with the same performance or not.

Comment: Can run? Maybe, depends on the technology stack your application uses and the technology the other application server supports (JSP version, Mojarra version, and so on). Same performance? You just have to do some performance, load and stress tests on your application in both servers to answer yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some google

for terms like [glassfish vs tomcat](https://www.google.com/search?q=glassfish%20vs%20tomcat&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) , [tomcat vs jboss](https://www.google.com/search?q=tomcat%20vs%20jboss&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) and so on... in order to get the general idea and in order to see the pros and cons

INMO , in general they are the more or less the same , it also depends on the kind of support you want to get in the future.. some are free some cost hundreds of $$$ and even more

Regarding the migrating from one web server to another : If you write your app tomcat and want to migrate to glassfish it will be doable.. but you probably will have to do some googling in order to do the needed fine tuning and placing the missing jars that the new web server require...

Comment: so the app will run the same on both with just some minor changes required ?

Comment: not always minor changes... but it is indeed doable (depend on how complicated your app) and of course some web servers will have better performance than the other , but it also depends on how good you will configure the web server...

Answer (score 1):

> Does JSF (or any other java EE framework) need their own type of
>   servers, or if a server can host jsp/servlets is capable of hosting
>   JSF apps ?

If a server can run jsp/servlets, it can run JSF (JSf behind the scenes is using servlets). You just need to bundle the jsf implementation library (example: Mojarra jar file) with your webapp.

> Does applications developed using Glassfish work on TomCat servers or
>   JBOSS or any other?

Tomcat is a servlet container, it is not a standard Java EE application server. In other words, Tomcat doesn't have an EJB container or CDI (Context and Dependency Injection) container. So if you used any EJBs or CDI in your application developed using JBoss or Glassfish, it wouldn't work on Tomcat.

Glassfish and Jboss have full support for Java EE applications. So, anything developed using Glassfish can technically work on JBoss. You might have to do little tweaks such as pre-pending the JNDI names etc.

Hope that helps.